# How to switch to another view on click of annotation pin in MKMapView in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am making an iPhone app where in there is a requirement of a map.

I am using MKMapView for that. I have placed an annotation at a particular point.

I want that when I click that annotation pin then it should take me to another view controller.

How can I do this? I am new in this MKMapView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go to another viewcontroller by clicking the pin directly. There is this delegate of MapView

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
  {
     // Here push your view controller
  }
```